# Full Height Navigation Bar Strange Error

Tags: html, css, navigation, height

Ok so I made ul height 100% and li a to block level but for some reason I cannot get my vertical navigation to be full height. Well, really I want it to stop right at the footer. So here's the code: I put background-color on the ul but it's not going to the bottom for some reason

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}  

body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 19px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}

#pagewrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -174px; 
}

#pagewrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

#footer, #pagewrap:after {
    height: 174px;
}

.sub:last-child {
    border: 0px;
}

#footer {
    background-color:  #00e600;
}

.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.sub {
    padding: 12px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #00e600;
    color: white;
    border-right: solid white 1px;  
}


.sub:last-child {
    border: 0px;
}

#nav {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: brown;
    padding-right: 20px;  
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: brown;
}

#nav li {
    margin: 0px; 
}

#nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: pink;
    background-color: brown;  
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color:  white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px white;
}

<body>  
    <div id="pagewrap">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--
<footer id="footer">

</footer>

-->


<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum </div>
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Would anybody be able to spot the problem?

Comment: Where is the jsfiddle?

Comment: Edited, it's in the OP. thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xjosdhjh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish exactly what you're looking for (stopping the vertical navigation right before the footer, you'll need to combine a couple different styles. Your original issue is most likely that there's a parent element between the `html, body` that needs to have 100% height added. Luckily there's a more efficient way now. Add the following to the `#nav` styling:

```
#nav {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This will make the `nav` 100% of the viewport height. To accommodate the footer, as well, update to the following code:

```
#nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 174px);
}
```

This calculates the difference between the full screen height and the height of the footer, which is currently 174px. Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/44655gw4/1/

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to cover the gap between the nav and that footer?

Comment: There is indeed. Just remove the `margin-bottom: 10px;` style from the #nav element. Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/44655gw4/2/